# Would a professor be angry if I neglect to take classes within the research I'm working in as an undergraduate?

Tags: research-undergraduate

I am an undergrad currently working in the lab with a great professor and doing interesting work. I promised the professor that I would take more relevant courses related to the research I'm working on to help me with my research.

However, I found that there are some other courses that are more interesting to me and more marketable as a career skill. I want to take those instead but also continue working with him, but do you think he'd be angry if I went against his strong recommendation to take more relevant classes?

Answer (score 4):

The professor can certainly be angry with your decision to go against his recommendation; however, this is far more likely to happen if you do it without explaining him several things:

- your intention of not taking the courses he recommends
- your motivation to take the other courses instead
- and most importantly, your motivation and expectations from working in his lab

You certainly don't have to follow his advice and try to explore as many options as you want as an undergraduate, but I would give your professor an explanation BEFORE and a chance to make his points one more time. If the professor is actually "great" and professional, he would totally listen to you and understand your decision – nothing to be mad about.

Sometimes, professors treat some of their undergrad assistants similar to the grad ones. That is usually a good sign – you seem professional and valuable enough. However, this comes at a cost of them unintentionally assuming you want to continue working in their lab forever. With you clearly explaining your reasons, motivations, and aspirations, you have a chance to be as professional as you can be and maintaining the best possible relationships.

Answer (score 2):

The professor would not be called great if he would be angry with your choice towards a career which you think is best suited for you. There is no point in following all the professor's advice. You are not a PhD student, you are an undergrad - the time when you should explore as much as possible.

Of course, you could convince that you are doing those courses informally through video lectures or self studies and might want to discuss with him after finishing some of those courses.

I don't see any reason why I would be 'angry' if my undergrad research student does not follow all my advice, if it could give my research a different direction altogether.

Answer (score 2):

While your advisor may want you to take classes relevant to his interests, ultimately, **it’s your degree and your career.**

Where the two are in conflict, you need to focus on what will help you graduate and move on to the next stage of your career. If that means getting a job in industry, then you should focus on that. On the other hand, if this is someone you want to continue working with beyond undergraduate research, you may want to see about meeting him halfway—take some courses you want, and some courses he wants you to take.

Answer (score 1):

**Would your professor be angry?**
(In the U.S. context) professors understand that undergraduates are still exploring their classes; you are not contractually obligated to take those further courses (unless you signed something to that effect). It would be (within the range of) normal for a professor in this situation to feel disappointed or upset when learning that you had changed your mind about this course of action he was expecting, but he should not take it out on you or be vindictive.

**Why might he care?**
In the near term, if you do not take the recommended classes, you may not be able to advance further on the work you're doing with the professor; this might mean the end of the job. Backing out on what you describe as a "promise" would be bad form in general. If the promise was also part of why the prof currently has you in his lab (investment in training you, with the hope that you will train yourself further), then the promise has even more importance.

**What might be the effect on you?**
So, this might end your job in the lab, if the coursework is a necessary co-requisite. You might find it hard to get the professor's recommendation for graduate school, if you choose to pursue it. (And/or the professor would have a harder time making a convincing case for your interest and skill in the field.)

**Red flag check**
Is the professor prone to expressing anger? Did the professor force you to make a promise about this? If either of these is true, you should find an ombudsman (university position of being a neutral 3rd party) or talk with the DUS (director of undergraduate studies in the professor's department) or another person you trust for advice.

If you are still interested in taking the other courses, I would recommend that you:

1. Study their syllabi and see if any skills meaningfully relate to the skills you would get in the recommended classes.
2. Look up on job sites what some of the marketable applications of the recommended classes are
3. Talk with other students in the lab or seniors in the major about the value of the skills from those classes.
4. Consider options you're willing to accept (e.g. not working in lab and taking desired classes; taking one recommended class and one new class; taking just the recommended classes and honing your lab skills).
5. Decide whether to bring the dilemma to the professor (if you trust him and your mind is truly not made up, and if his reaction to the different paths will impact your decision--e.g. whether or not you can keep your job in lab).
6. Otherwise, if you decide not to take the classes you promised to, tell the professor as soon as your decision is firm, so he has as many options as possible.